# Are modes and scales the same?

Tags: scales, modes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between a mode and a scale?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/5382/what-is-the-difference-between-a-mode-and-a-scale)

Are modes and scales not the same? If not, how are modes different from scales?

Comment: Wikipedia: [Scale (music)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_(music)), [Mode (music)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_(music))

Comment: No.  A scale is a stack of root notes of each degree of the mode.  A mode is a type of musical scale coupled with a set of characteristic melodic behaviors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Modes belong to scales. The modes are seven different scales. They come from the major scale, and they are applied to give different "colours" to the music.